# Conditional Merge in SAS data step

Tags: sas

I have two tables, which for the sake of simplicity are:

Table 1:

```
Date     ID
20170401  X
20170501  Y
20170601  Z
```

Table 2:

```
Date     ID
20170201  Z
20170301  Y
20170501  X
```

I want to create a new table which has everything from table 1, unless the ID occurred at a previous date in table 2.

The desired output for table 1 and 2 would be:

```
Date    ID 
20170401 X
```

This is what I currently have. I'm not sure where to put the conditional merge:

```
data new; 
merge table1 table2(in=b); 
by date ID; 
if not b [where table2.date is before table1.date]; 
run;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SAS overwrites variables with the same names, so rename date in table2. Merge on ID and only keep if it's in table1 and passes your date criterion. Then drop the date2 column as it's not needed.

```
data new; 
  merge table1 (in=a) table2(in=b rename=(date=date2)); 
  by ID; 
  if a and not(date2<date);
  drop date2;
  run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this solution is merging IDs from table1 with dates in table2 that does not exist in table1. If I only want IDs from table1 with dates from table1, how would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: That's more complicated, you want to match ID, date and then exclude an ID if it has *another* row in table2 that has a date earlier than the matched?